# tomli-w, adding arrays from a python script

Tags: python, toml

I have a toml file like this

```
[[fruits]]
fruit_property =x

[[fruits]]
fruit_property =x

[[fruits]]
fruit_property =x
```

And I want to encode this from a python script. So far in python i have done

```
fruits= [
 {'fruit_property':x},{'fruit_property':y},  {'fruit_property':z}, 
]

toml_string = tomli_w.dumps(fruits)
```

and then writing the string to a file. However, this doesn't convert the array of dicts, and instead just keeps them the same way my code has them. I've looked and can't find any documentation for this, has anyone run into similar issues?

However, this does not convert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like a *bug* in [`tomli-w`](https://github.com/hukkin/tomli-w) (even after adding an outer `"fruits"` key).

I suggest you to [`dumps`](https://tomlkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#tomlkit.dumps) your fruits object with [`tomlkit`](https://github.com/sdispater/tomlkit) (`!pip install tomlkit`) :

```py
import tomlkit

fruits = [
    {"fruit_property": "x"}, {"fruit_property": "y"}, {"fruit_property": "z"},
]

toml_string = tomlkit.dumps({"fruits": fruits})
```

Output :

```
print(toml_string)

[[fruits]]
fruit_property = "x"

[[fruits]]
fruit_property = "y"

[[fruits]]
fruit_property = "z"
```

Comment: ah interesting, i would not have guessed it's a bug. This works, thank you!